# SQL Server: self-referencing constraints not supported

Tags: sql-server, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I currently have a database schema, where a `member` can belong to a `sub-group` and a `sub-group` can belong to a `group`. I want to redesign the model to be more flexible (e.g. there could be a sub-sub-group etc.). So I wanted to associate a group with itself, so it could have a "parent" group.

Using NodeJS, [`sequelize`](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize) and [`sequelize-typescript`](https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript), I have the following definition:

```
@Table
export default class Group extends Model<Group> {
 
    @Column
    name: string;

    @ForeignKey(() => Group)
    @Column
    parentId: number;

    @HasOne(() => Group)
    parent: Group;

// + associations with the members model

}
```

However, I get the error:

> MSSQL does not support self-referential constraints, we will remove it but we recommend restructuring your query

I thought self-joins were possible in SQL Server - is this the case? If so, is this a `sequelize` issue, or should I be approaching this in a different way?

Comment: sql-server has no problems with self joins. must be something in your js script which i am not familiar with

Comment: Is this an error or just a warning? It looks like sequelize wants to generate cascading DRI with a recursive foreign key relationship but SQL Server doesn't allow multiple cascade paths. I don't know sequelize but maybe it can perform needed cascading actions with a `NO ACTION` foreign key.

Comment: @DanGuzman just a warning, but it seems as though it is just ignoring the association.

Comment: Not only does SQL Server support self-joins, it even supports this directly as a foreign key to the table itself. What it does not support (because the engine is overly conservative with potential cycles) is creating such keys with `ON [UPDATE/DELETE] CASCADE`. As it so happens, the default in sequelize is to specify `ON DELETE CASCADE`, and sequelize-typescript has no way to override that.

Comment: Can `onUpdate': 'NO ACTION'`help?

Comment: @GayathriMohan I am not sure what you mean? How would I use that? `sequelize-typescript` doesn't seem to have any reference to `onUpdate` anywhere in the docs.